Windows 10 Shortcut right click menu missing Pin to taskbar
I have an msys2 shortcut that runs C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -msys. I want to pin this shortcut to my taskbar or start menu, but the Right-click menu for this shortcut does not contain a Pin to Start or Pin to Taskbar option.
Dragging and dropping it to the task bar does nothing. Answers.microsoft.com suggested prefixing the command with "explorer" which did add Pin to taskbar to the menu but doing so and using it started explorer.exe window instead. I tried prefixing it with "cmd /C start C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -msys" which also could be pinned and doing so did run MSYS but also left a Windows terminal running.
How can I pin this shortcut to the taskbar without either a new Explorer window loading or a Terminal window showing?

Changing the Shortcut to "cmd.exe /C C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -msys" adds Pin to taskbar to the right-click menu and after doing so, clicking it there runs MSYS without a Windows terminal remaining.
